# Filter using a vector that has the column names

Tags: r, database, dataframe, data.table

I have searched through different questions and I don't get any solution...  Sorry if the question is repeated.

I have this data.table or dataframe:

```
a <- rep(1:8)
b <- rep(c("Incorrect","Correct", "Correct", "Incorrect"), each = 1)
c <- rep(c("Correct", "Incorrect", "Correct", "Correct"), each = 1)
df <- data.table(a,b,c)

df

   a         b         c
1: 1 Incorrect   Correct
2: 2   Correct Incorrect
3: 3   Correct   Correct
4: 4 Incorrect   Correct
5: 5 Incorrect   Correct
6: 6   Correct Incorrect
7: 7   Correct   Correct
8: 8 Incorrect   Correct
```

To filter by all the Incorrect values I keep all the name variables/columns that I want to filter in a vector. Then I copy-paste by the length of the vector I need (In this case I filter by 1 and 2).

```
columns <- c("b","c")

df[get(columns[1])== "Incorrect" | get(columns[2])=="Incorrect",]

   a         b         c
1: 1 Incorrect   Correct
2: 2   Correct Incorrect
3: 4 Incorrect   Correct
4: 5 Incorrect   Correct
5: 6   Correct Incorrect
6: 8 Incorrect   Correct
```

Is there a way to do it without copy-pasting each value of the columns vector i want to filter? I have at least 20 variable names... Should I consider a different approach?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank's in advance!

Comment: rep(1:8) equals 1:8.

Comment: According to the given example rows with all "correct" entries need to be dropped, ie keep the ones that have at least one "incorrect"

Comment: @desval my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you want to drop a row if all values in the selected columns are "correct".

```
columns <- c("b","c")
df[apply(df[,..columns], 1, function(x) any( x=="Incorrect")) ]

   a         b         c
1: 1 Incorrect   Correct
2: 2   Correct Incorrect
3: 4 Incorrect   Correct
4: 5 Incorrect   Correct
5: 6   Correct Incorrect
6: 8 Incorrect   Correct
```

If `df` is a `data.frame`:

```
df[apply(df[,columns], 1, function(x) any( x=="Incorrect")),]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ids <- df[, melt(df, id.vars = "a")
          ][, if (any(value == "Incorrect")) a, by = a]$V1
df[a %in% ids]

#    a         b         c
# 1: 1 Incorrect   Correct
# 2: 2   Correct Incorrect
# 3: 4 Incorrect   Correct
# 4: 5 Incorrect   Correct
# 5: 6   Correct Incorrect
# 6: 8 Incorrect   Correct
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest an approach using a text chain to concatenate all conditions an the evaluate it for the filter:

```
#Data
a <- 1:8
b <- rep(c("Incorrect","Correct", "Correct", "Incorrect"), each = 1)
c <- rep(c("Correct", "Incorrect", "Correct", "Correct"), each = 1)
df <- data.frame(a,b,c,stringsAsFactors = F)
#Vars
columns <- c("b","c")
```

Here, we build the text chain:

```
#Chain
chain <- paste0('df$',columns,'=="Incorrect"')
chain2 <- paste0(chain,collapse = '|')
```

Now the filter:

```
#Filter
df[eval(parse(text=chain2)),]
```

The output:

```
  a         b         c
1 1 Incorrect   Correct
2 2   Correct Incorrect
4 4 Incorrect   Correct
5 5 Incorrect   Correct
6 6   Correct Incorrect
8 8 Incorrect   Correct
```

I don't have the `data.table` package that is why I created data as `data.frame` but the solution also works for `data.table` objects.

Answer (score 0):

An approach you can consider to use `c_across()` in `dplyr` 1.0.0 and higher

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(any(str_detect(c_across(c(b, c)), "Incorrect")))

# Rowwise: 
# a b         c        
# <int> <chr>     <chr>    
# 1     1 Incorrect Correct  
# 2     2 Correct   Incorrect
# 3     4 Incorrect Correct  
# 4     5 Incorrect Correct  
# 5     6 Correct   Incorrect
# 6     8 Incorrect Correct
```